# Pull request to freeCodeCamp guide - how to proceed

Tags: github

I wanted to contribute to the FCC guides and I actually did.
This is my fork to the repository [image]

Link: https://github.com/BitYog/guides

However, when I open the main guides repository, I don't see my changes being shown anywhere. What do I do so that my changes are merged and committed into the main repo?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see your commits in the original repository, because you didn't create a pull request against that repository, but against your fork. In other words, you opened a pull request to merge `BitYog/guides#BitYog-patch-1` into `BitYog/guides#master`. With that, you updated your own `master` branch, but not that of `freeCodeCamp/guides`.

Your changes will only show up when a pull request into `freeCodeCamp/guides#master` is merged. For that to happen, you need to open a [new pull request](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/guides/compare) in the freeCodeCamp repository and request to merge either your `master` or `BitYog-patch-1` branch into `master`.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Click on the [link](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/guides/compare) I posted, and compare their master branch (on the left) with your master branch (on the right). You should see the changes you made. Then write a nice message explaining what you did, and open the pull request. Here is a link to GitHub's support pages describing this as well: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

Comment: Hey jdno, I'm really grateful for your help. I finally        created the pull request. Thanks again.